# Python (seaborn): Specify dimensions of the pairgrid when calling pairplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn to produce ten scatterplots of each 'independent' variable (X1,...,X10) against one dependent variable (y). My issue is the output is returned as a 1x10 grid, rather than an 'approximately square' grid. Ideally, the grid would be 3x4 (but with 2 subplots in the final row instead of 4).

My output is as follows:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(200,11))
x_column_names = ['X'+str(v) for v in df.columns][1:]
df.columns = ['y'] + x_column_names
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=x_column_names, y_vars="y", kind="reg")
```

[image]

How can I make the grid 'approximately square' if an arbitrary number of indepedent variables are used (10 are used in the above example)?

And bonus question: How can I include the lowess rather than linear regression fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [feature request](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2121) that hasn't been implemented yet (but is a good idea).

One way to deal with this would be to hack `FacetGrid` to set up the figure:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(pd.DataFrame(x_column_names), col=0, col_wrap=4, sharex=False)
for ax, xvar in zip(g.axes, x_column_names):
    sns.regplot(data=df, x=xvar, y="y", ax=ax)
g.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Alternatively, here's how you could set up the figure using matplotlib:

```
# Work out the figure parameters
nplot = len(x_column_names)
ncol = 4
nrow = nplot // ncol + bool(nplot % ncol)

height, aspect = 3, 1
figsize = height * aspect * ncol, height * nrow

# Set up the figure
f, axs = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, figsize=figsize, sharey=True)
for ax, xvar in zip(axs.flat, x_column_names):
    sns.regplot(data=df, x=xvar, y="y", ax=ax)

# Remove axes without any data    
for ax in axs.flat[nplot:]:
    ax.remove()

# Turn off interior y axis labels
plt.setp(axs[:, 1:], ylabel="")

f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can specify height and aspect using height=, aspect=. height*aspect gives width of each plot.
follow this link for documentation [seaborn.pairplot doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html).

Comment: This changes the dimensions of each subplot rather than the grid dimensions.